# How to convert currency from the dataset which was know beforehand in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have **a dictionary** with *the key is the date* and *the value is revenue from the date*, as shown in the picture

**Dictionary data:**

[image]

I also have a dataframe of the currency of each date, as shown in the picture

**Dataframe of the currency:**

[image]

So, how to make a dataframe with 2 columns. The first columns is the date, and the second column is the converted revenue

Expected Values:

| Date | Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-11-01 | 5853302 |
| 2019-11-02 | 17415125 |
| 2019-11-03 | 19684777 |
| ... | ... |
| 2020-03-29 | 1227610 |

Comment: add expected output to your question - a dataframe with your desired data

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information

Comment: @adlofMerlin The dictionary image is the same as the dataframe image. Also it's better to paste the sample data as text instead of images so users can copy-paste it when working on answers.

Comment: can you please tell that How are you converting these values?doing any calculations or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`map()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the revenues by `id` and multiply by `idr`.

Assuming the revenue dictionary is named `revenue` and the currency dataframe is named `currency`:

```py
result = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': currency.id,
    'Revenue': currency.id.astype(str).map(revenue) * currency.idr,
})

#       Date       Revenue
# 2019-11-01  5.853307e+06
# 2019-11-02  1.741513e+07
# 2019-11-03  1.968478e+07
# 2019-11-04  2.132557e+07
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work: (here df1 is your original dataframe)

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date','revenue'])

df2['date'] = df1['date']
df2['revenue'] = df1['idr'].apply(lambda x: x*10) #replace x*10 with whatever other calculation you want to do
```